# Ideas for student parallel programming project

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I'm looking to do a parallel programming project in C (probably using pthreads or maybe OpenMP) for a class. It will done by a group of about four students, and should take about 4 weeks. I was thinking it would be interesting to attack some NP-complete problem with a more complex algorithm like a genetic algo with simulated annealing, but I'm not sure if it would be a big enough project.

Anyone knew of any cool problems that could benefit from a parallel approach?

Comment: parallel as in multi-threading/processing or parallel as in distributed among multiple computers?

Comment: Does it need to be so theoretical? In real life NP-Complete and C and multicore do not really mix that well IMO - they are on the opposite sides of the spectrum. You could just do some signal / audio / image processing instead.

Comment: sorry, should have clarified, parallel as in multi-threaded, it'll run on one machine

Comment: Hamish, why wouldn't NP-Complete problems mix well with multi-threading? (Although I agree, a language like LISP would be much nicer then C for a lot of the NP-Complete stuff)

Comment: Yeah ... from practicality point of view. C gets you lots of efficiency, but is painfully slow to program. Lisp / Clojure / Python are for algorithms. Peter Norvig prefers Python. You have not told us what class this is for.

Comment: This is for my parallel and distributed programming class, so the focus is more on learning to parallelize a complex problem. I'm a third year, but there are quite a few graduate students in the class.

Comment: Are you restricted to a particular programming language? I personally would go high level .. or perhaps use this new language called Go. Yeah - give Go a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember a 'learning' project at our university about parallelizing alpha-beta pruning algorithms. Alpha-beta pruning itself isn't too complicated and has quite large complexity. If you parallelize it you'll need to install some signaling/data sharing to really benefit from the parallelization. Otherwise some threads would go too often or too deep into branches that already were considered too bad by other threads. I think that can be a good use case.